# K8S Ingress controller with both public and private IP

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster setup with Azure App Gateway and a private site is hosted using the private IP. Now I have to deploy another site on same cluster with public access (Public IP). How can I setup a ingress controller with both private and public IP?

*Thanks in advance.*

*Private site configuration is already there in the ingress controller

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/948